# Prerequisites for "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" by Rosen and Ireland

Tags: number-theory, book-recommendation

I want to learn number theory for my programming as many of the questions are related to the mathematics which is being asked in Hiring Challenges as well as for increasing my knowledge of cryptography. I have studied cryptography from Khan Academy and no doubt they were enough for me to pass my exams but I feel that I have just touched the surface of number theory and I was amazed by it. Many of the aptitude exams in India uses the application of number theory. But they only tell you the trick but I want to learn how do this trick work correctly. So I bought the book [A Classical Introduction To Modern Number Theory](https://www.amazon.in/Classical-Introduction-Modern-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/038797329X) but I am finding some difficulty to understand it. Have I missed something before it which should be read? I know calculus and Discrete Mathematics(not thoroughly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book assumes some knowledge of abstract algebra.  If you don't know what a group or ring is, then you'll find the book heavy sledding.  You might try Ken Rosen's *Elementary Number Theory* (different Rosen) or Burton's *Elementary Number Theory* first.  I would consider Ireland and Rosen as a good *second* course in Number Theory.

Comment: @[B.Goddard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/362009/b-goddard) I have gone to [Ken Rosen's](https://www.amazon.in/Elementary-Number-Theory-Kenneth-Rosen/dp/9332544999/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1512821155&sr=8-7&keywords=elementary+number+theory) book on Amazon but the reviews are awful. I don't think that I should go for it. Probably the latter will be better. And I know about Groups and Ring but only theory. I didn't have feel of them what actually they are.

Comment: I think Rosen and Burton have about the same flavor.  You might look at Emil Grosswald's _Topics in Number Theory_.  It has some of the algebraic stuff in it, but doesn't club you over the head.

Comment: I have bought Burton's Elementary Number Theory. Thanks.